# Kinesis Iterator age vs Lambda Iterator Age

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-kinesis

What is the difference between the two? Also, what does it mean to have a kinesis iterator age of 12 hours and lambda iterator age of 2 hours. The configuration is very simple & basic (i.e only 1 event source mapping : Kinesis stream -> Lambda)

- Parallelization factor = 1
- Number of Shards = 1
- No enhanced Fan-out.

Comment: How did it go? Still unclear what they mean?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There can be **multiple consumers** of a single kinesis stream. For example, an EC2 instance, ECS container and a lambda function can read the same stream concurrently.

[GetRecords.IteratorAge](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/streams/latest/dev/monitoring-with-cloudwatch.html) is a **global** (per stream) metric. It measures "The age of the last record in all GetRecords calls made against a Kinesis stream", regardless of which consumer called it.

[lambda iterator age](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/with-kinesis.html#events-kinesis-metrics) is only an **individual lambda function** specific measure. It will not account for other consumers. It is constructed based on [MillisBehindLatest](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/kinesis/latest/APIReference/API_GetRecords.html#Streams-GetRecords-response-MillisBehindLatest) value which each `GetRecords` call returns.

> what does it mean to have a kinesis iterator age of 12 hours and lambda iterator age of 2 hours.

This means that the given **lambda is 2 hours behind** in processing the stream. However, since a stream can be read by multiple consumers, "kinesis iterator age of 12 hours" means that there is **some other consumer** which is 12 hours behind.

Answer (score 0):

Great question. What @Marcin said about multiple consumers is true, but there is more to it than just consumer count.

I raised a support case with AWS to clear up this exact situation, as I couldn't rationalize it based on the documentation and metrics. Here is the AWS Analytics Support Engineers response, verbatim:

> I performed more researches by reviewing the internal and external
> articles. I confirmed Kinesis stream [IteratorAgeMilliseconds] and
> Lambda function [IteratorAge] measure the different time.
>
> Kinesis stream [IteratorAgeMilliseconds] : It's easy to understand. It
> is the difference between the current time and when the last record of
> the GetRecords call.
>
> Lambda function [IteratorAge] :  When we use Lambda function as the
> consumer from Kinesis stream event source, there is a Lambda service
> called event source mapping in front of the actual function. The event
> source mapping read batches of records from the stream and invoke
> Lambda function. [IteratorAge] measure the time from event source
> mapping read the records till the actual function starts to process
> the records. As you might be already aware of, event source mapping
> does the polling at the steady rate of exactly one GetRecords call per
> second for each shard in the stream. The fact is that even after the
> records are arrived in event source mapping, they are not necessarily
> sent to the function and processed straight away. The batches are
> processed only when the previous Lambda invocation has completed,
> providing the records meet the batch size. Before that, the batches
> are hold in the internal buffer. If the previous batch takes longer to
> process, or something goes wrong, event source mapping has to re-read
> the batch or Lambda function has to re-process the batch, all of these
> contribute to [IteratorAge].
>
> I found this external article explains Lambda consumers quite well
> under "Lambda - Let’s now finally talk about Lambda!" section so share
> with you: - [X] Mastering AWS Kinesis Data Streams, Part 2 -
> https://dev.solita.fi/2020/12/21/kinesis-streams-part-2.html
>
> In summary, Kinesis stream [IteratorAgeMilliseconds] looks from
> Kinesis side and measure the age of the last obtained record from the
> stream whereas Lambda function [IteratorAge] looks from Lambda side
> and measure the age of the latest record that event source mapping
> send to the function to process.
>
> I hope I have provided a clear explanation in the difference between 2
> metrics but if you need further clarification please do not hesitate
> to get back to me and I will do all I can to help.

Personally, I'm still confused and dubious that some of the details are correct.

Comment: in summary, AWS have now implemented auto ChatGPT support